# Microsoft Visual Studio C++. Que significa el error "The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Bueno mi problema es el siguiente, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void datos();
int cantVocales(char*);

char nombre[20];

int main()
{
    datos();

    cout << "La cantidad de vocales en el nombre son: " << cantVocales(nombre) << endl;

    return 0;
}


void datos()
{
    cout << "Ingrese su nombre: " << endl;
    cin.getline(nombre, 20, '\n');

    strupr(nombre);
}

int cantVocales(char *punteroNombre)
{
    int cont = 0;

    while (*punteroNombre != '\0')
    {
        switch (*punteroNombre)
        {
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U': cont++;
        }
        punteroNombre++;
    }

    return cont;
}
```

pero cuando compilo, el visual studio me tira esto:

'strup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _strupr

el caso es que hice el cambio de nombre primero a _strupr, me tiro error y luego a cambiar por _strupr_s, justo alli con esa ultima me dejo compilar y todo bien, quisiera saber por que se produce este error?, el codeblock no tuve que hacer el cambio de nombre ni campoco en devC++ y eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El codigo que usas, recoge metodos antiguos del C. El motivo por el cual otros programas como DevC++ y Code::Blocks te permiten hacer esas cosas riesgosas es porque usan el compilador MinGW que admite usar leyes de 1998. En la ultima decada C++ ha evolucionado tanto que ya es torpe decir que C es igual que C++. La causa de tu problema es que Visual te esta diciendo que lo que haces compromete muchas cosas riesgosas y por estandares que se desarrollan han botado por completo estas funciones antiguas.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
    std::string str = "hola que tal";
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Este codigo hace lo que pides en C++(como no explicaste asumo que lo unico que quieres es la forma de convertir a mayusculas un string). Porfavor revisa los cambios de C++ 11 y posteriores ya que el compilador de Microsoft VC/C++ no admite usar antiguo C/C++ en cambio solo permite usar desde el estandar C++14 a posteriores. Si nesesitas usar codigo del legado instala Visual Studio 2010 o mas antiguos.